# I can't start Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

When I run *run-nifi.bat* it pops up for a split second but then auto closes. I don't really understand this, I just need it for a university class and it hadn't been properly explained, so I'm just trying on my own really.

I get this in my nifi-app.log:

```
2021-05-29 17:07:30,179 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Launching NiFi...
2021-05-29 17:07:30,450 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.security.kms.CryptoUtils Determined default nifi.properties path to be 'D:\SYSTEM\Downloads\nifi-1.13.2-bin\nifi-1.13.2\.\conf\nifi.properties'
2021-05-29 17:07:30,454 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Loaded 188 properties from D:\SYSTEM\Downloads\nifi-1.13.2-bin\nifi-1.13.2\.\conf\nifi.properties
2021-05-29 17:07:30,465 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Loaded 188 properties
2021-05-29 17:07:30,705 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Started Bootstrap Listener, Listening for incoming requests on port 63487
2021-05-29 17:07:30,711 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:576)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:565)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:595)
    at org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener.sendCommand(BootstrapListener.java:102)
    at org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener.start(BootstrapListener.java:74)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:102)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:71)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:303)
2021-05-29 17:07:30,712 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2021-05-29 17:07:30,712 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).
```

I've tried editing the web properties in the config files in case the default was wrong. Right now it's on, but the errors are the same:

```
nifi.web.http.host=localhost
nifi.web.http.port=9090
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
```

I have Windows 10 Home Edition.

Comment: Have you tried 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Yes, thats the default option.

Comment: Windows firewall preventing it from binding?

Comment: I've tried it with firewall off and on, neither did anything.

Comment: Please check for user or any permission related issues. Try `Run as Administrator` or elevated command prompt.

Comment: What version of java are you using? If you have different java - have you set Java_home environment variable?

Comment: Java 8 JDK 16 JAVA_HOME is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\

Comment: Did you read the system requirements? https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#system_requirements

Comment: Yes, I did I have Java 8 on a Windows 10 pc, both fitting the minimum requirements and i doubt that nifi needs more than 56 GB disk space.

Comment: But your Java_Home is JDK16?

Comment: As I stated earlier, yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

NiFi requires Java 8 or Java 11 to run. So your environment variables should point to the correct directory with Java 8 or Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable? I would recommend checking the config files and telling the configs where to find the Java installation

Answer (score -1):

You might be missing URL ACL

Maybe you can try below command:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://computername:port/ user=username
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/246798/191420